# C# - How to include Outlook signature in an email that contains images?

Tags: c#, outlook

Here is my code to send the email in Outlook 2013:

```C#
public void GenerateEmail(OutEmail outEmail)
{
    var objOutlook = new Application();
    var mailItem = (MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));
    mailItem.To = outEmail.SendTo;
    mailItem.Subject = outEmail.Subject;

    mailItem.RTFBody = outEmail.Body + outEmail.Signature;
    mailItem.Attachments.Add(outEmail.Attachment);

    Outlook.Account account = objOutlook.Session.Accounts["mail@email.com"];
    mailItem.SendUsingAccount = account;
    mailItem.Send();
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}
```

Now, `outEmail.Signature` contains the HTML of the Outlook signature as a string, found at: `C:\Users\SO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures` It formats the signature correctly apart from including the images. How can I include the signature with images such that I can create a new signature in Outlook and can include it within the e-mail WITHOUT needing an end user to edit the signature HTML. I don't mind doing it programmatically but I would need to be sure that it would work for all signatures that could be potentially added.

**EDIT:** Possible solution? In the HTML, find instances of the `img` tag and remove the `{SignatureName}_FILES\` and then attach everything inside the `{SignatureName}_FILES\` folder to the email?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

try below mentioned

```
mailItem.GetInspector.Activate();
var signature = mailItem.HTMLBody;
mailItem.HTMLBody = EmailBody + signature;
```

Comment: You cannot blindly concatenate 2 HTML strings and expects a well formatted HTML string in return. The two HTML strings must be merged.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook inserts the signature when you call `MailItem.Display` or access `MailItem.GetInspector` (you do not have to do anything with the returned object).

If you want to programmatically insert a signature, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) exposes [RDOSignature](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignature.htm) object which implements `ApplyTo` method.

**UPDATE**: as of the latest (Summer 2017) builds of Outlook, `GetInspector` trick no longer works. Now only `MailItem.Display` adds the signature to an unmodified message.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. You always seem to come to the rescue Dmitry on Outlook questions.  Just a question, does GetInspector display a popup at all when sending the email (I don't want a pop up and can't test atm). Also, it should be noted that I do not want to display the default signature, I want to be able to specify which signature to display.

Comment: GetInspector will not display anything. Try to set the MailItem.SendUsingAccount before calling GetInspector. Also keep in mind that GetInspector  must be called before the message body is set; and when you set it, you must merge the signature in the message body with the value that you are trying to set.

Comment: From what I can tell MailItem.GetInspector.Activate() does in fact display the MailMessage UI briefly and then closes again. It does make the signature appear as supposed, but how to prevent it from showing the UI?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that one can call MailItem.GetInspector.CurrentItem(); and then it will not open anything, while still have the effect that the signature is inserted.

Comment: What version did it stop working, and has it since been fixed in latest builds?

Comment: Don't know the exact version #, it stopped working Summer 2017. I very much doubt it will be fixed since that wasn't a documented behavior of GetInspector but rather a side effect.