# VBA Outlook Signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have tried inserting different codes to get the defualt signature in Outlook to show at the end of this line of code when it generates an email. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim signature As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "I recently reviewed a call of yours and the information that we reviewed in our coaching session is as follows:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "Call Duration: " & Sheets("Sheet1 (13)").Range("j38").Value & vbCrLf & _
              "Date: " & Sheets("Sheet1 (13)").Range("j39").Value & vbCrLf & _
              "Coaching Feedback: " & Sheets("Sheet1 (13)").Range("J40").Value & vbCrLf & signature
                  On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = Range("D39")
        .CC = Range("G39")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Quality Audit Coaching"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820914/c-sharp-how-to-include-outlook-signature-in-an-email-that-contains-images/25825218#25825218

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233264/inserting-signature-into-outlook-email-from-excel-vba

Comment: See below answer and let me know if it worked - thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I see you have Dim signature variables Statement but I don't see you assigning to any object.*

*Try the following if its not HTML body*

```
With xOutMail
    .To = Range("D39")
    .CC = Range("G39")
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Quality Audit Coaching"
    .Display
    .Body = xMailBody & .Body
   ' .Send
End With
```

*And if its HTML Body then change it to **`.HTMLBody = xMailBody & .HTMLBody`***

*Or you can set `Dim signature variable`*

*Example*

```
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

With xOutMail
    .Display
     signature = .HTMLBody
End With
```

***[MSDN HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))***

*Returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string. Read/write.*

***[MSDN .Body Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.Body)***

*Returns or sets a String representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. Read/write.*

Comment: Concatenating two HTML strings is a bad idea - they really need to be merged.

Comment: Signature will not be added to a newly created item, you need to call Display for that. MailItem.GetInspector used to do that too, but not anymore (as of summer 2017).

Comment: Ops I forgot about .`display` answer update and test it, It works @DmitryStreblechenko `.body` should work if the OP has no formatting on his signature