# Open draft email with signature

Tags: powershell, outlook, signature

I am trying to open an email with Powershell as a draft, which already has a signature displayed.

Is there any way to display the body and signature in the email? There is also often pictures in the signatures so would like to bring them across too if possible.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "my_email@outlook.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Show my signature"
$body = "<body>Test body `r`n`n</body>"
$temp = $mail.body
$mail.htmlbody=get-content $env:appdata\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm

$mail.body= $text +$mail.body + $temp

$mail.save()
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

**EDIT** Solution was to add body after .Display()

```
$mail.save()
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()

$body = "<body>Test body <br><br></body>"
$mail.HTMLbody = $body + $mail.HTMLbody
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820914/c-sharp-how-to-include-outlook-signature-in-an-email-that-contains-images/25825218#25825218

Comment: Thanks @DmitryStreblechenko for the response, when I leave out the HTML body, the signature comes up easy enough. How can I also preset what I want the email body to contain?

Comment: After the message is displayed, you need to merge the existing HTML body with your own data (insert it after the body tag).

Answer (score 0):

Outlook inserts the signature when you call the `Display` method. If the signature is not added then you don't have any signature set for the account under which the item is going to be sent. It seems you didn't set up a correct account that has the property set up by using the [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property.

The signatures are being kept as separate files in the `Signatures` folder. You can find this folder in the following location;

- Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

- Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

So, you can read the file content and modify the `HTMLBody` property.